# To-do list words

Tags: word-choice

I'm learning Chinese, and trying to use it more in my daily life, e.g. by making to-do lists in Chinese.
What's the Chinese term for a to-do list, and what are words you might use if you finish something on your list? In English, I would say 'tick', but might also say 'finished' or 'done'. Would you say 做了 or 办了 or maybe something else?

Comment: see online dictionaries: e.g. **iciba** :事先 **列出** 你的问题。你应该把所有必须做的事都 **列出来** ,把孩子的玩具 **列个单子**  (English at iciba),   , **bkrs**:列出,1) list
2) provide a list of
我要你 **列出** 所有的名单。 I would like you to provide a list of all the names. **ichacha** :    列出清单
    列单子,造表
    列清单,造表
    作...表, **LINE dictionary** : **列一个表** ，随身带着。 把它们做成一个清单，勾出你已做的。  

 Make a list of them and tick off the ones that you have done.

Comment: find "to-do list" in online dictionaries, e.g. iciba: 

 

任务清单（To-do List）的重要性毋庸置疑，建立有强行动性的任务清单可以让你更清楚地明白自己需要完成的任务，同时还保持了你 …
2

待办事项清单

另还需要一张详细的待办事项清单(to-do list)。 对于小型的团队－－大概不超过四个人的小组－－ 专案经理是可以分担做一些工作的。
3

列表

尽管任务列表（to-do list）听起来吓人和凝重，但我们总有些不那么重要或紧迫的人生小愿望或计划，比如我想尝的美食，想要喝的鸡 …
相关词条

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no exact word-to-word translate in Chinese. Generally we refer things like to-do list as 待办事项 (tasks to be finished) or 任务清单(list of tasks).

Just as @Khahoe Tan said, I recommend using 完成 or 已完成 to mark as `completed`.

Answer (score 5):

It is called 事項表 (items list).

the 'to do things' on a 'to- do- list' are items (事項)

事項= matters/ items

事項表 = a list of matters/items (that have to be dealt with)

Answer (score 4):

You can refer To-Do List as "未完成"(To be completed) Or “未完成列表”

For the word that can be used when finishing something, I would use “完成” which means "Completed" to indicates that a task is done. Of course, using a tick √ has no problem as well as it is easier and more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

It is also called `事务` that means you have not finished it.